# Getting Error 403 with Front End Azure Web App using App Gateway

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I have configured App Gateway and the backend of my App Gateway has two apps, one Front End Web App and another Function App.
The function app is talking to a Databricks instance from another tenant and getting data.
I have an API app that is sitting between my Front End and Function App.

After doing custom domain name binding for both my FE and Function App and making the custom domain name same as the App GW Https listeners, i get rerouted to the Front End web app when i try to browse to the Front End App via App Gateway.

But i get to see this error in the browser after i hit F12.
In the API web app i have CORS enabled and the URL mentioned is that of the custom domain of the FE web app.
Any idea why this error is coming still

```
Request URL: https://contoso-qa-8234.azurewebsites.net/datahub/negotiate
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403
Remote Address: 20.X.X.X:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

It says initiator is "**Preflight**" in red in the F12 window

The remote address IP is that of the IP that i see for the Front End Web App when i go to Custom Domain in App Services

Comment: Unless you have an actual requirement to use AppGateway, I'd switch to using Azure Front Door. No need then to do any custom domains etc on your AppServices. Since all will be served from the same URL through Front Door, CORS should not be an issue. Plus, it is most likely cheaper than AppGw

Comment: @silent At the moment we don't have AFD as a service in our environment. But any idea why it is flagging CORS as an issue, i have already added https://fe-qa.contoso.com:443 as one of the URLs in the API Web App apart from the actual azurewebsites.net URL of the FE app